# Blackbox by pattern in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am trying to blackbox all code on my website that has the word "jquery" in it.

There many files on my site with this phrase such as: jquery.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery-migrate.min.js, etc...

I've found many articles on the internet showing how to do this, however they are outdated and show older versions of Google Chrome.

Here are two articles from the Google developers:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing#how-to-blackbox

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code#blackbox_third_party_code

These are great articles from Google, however they both show different ways to do this.

I am running Windows 10 and Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit) and my settings panel has neither of these options.

Can someone please tell me how I can find the new blackbox by pattern interface?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to blackbox a script with version 54 either.

My Chrome Canary version 57 has a blackbox tab on the settings panel that works:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I'm not the only one.I went to update chrome and it says i'm up to date. Where can I find version 57?